# Why Form Unload event fails in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm doing a validation on a form Unload event to let user decide whether to close form or not, by displaying a message with yes/No button, and evaluating answer. In case user decides not to close form, I set Cancel = true so form remains open. That works fine but, if instead of closing form I close Access, by pressing Access' close button (X in upper right corner of window) validation works (message is displayed and user can answer No) but Cancel=true seems to be ignored (Access gets closed anyway).

Oddly, this happens only when I run .accdb file 'directly' by pressing enter or double-clicking over .accdb file. If I first open database in 'design' mode and then open form from objects list, then it behaves the way I expect when I press Access close button (message is shown, decide not to close form and form remains open (and so does Access of course)).

I'm using Access 2010, a customized Ribbon which opens form using Docmd.OpenForm via OnActionButton callback. Has anyone experienced the same thing?

I have implemented a workaround disabling Access close button but I'd rather not use one.

Comment: Why not go with disabling the Access X close? That's my preference. Actually, my code disables it only when users open the file, not the administrator (me).

Comment: @June7, well just for the sake of doing things as simple and straight forward as possible. But yes, I've tested it and seems my best bet. I  disabled Access X close button only while this particular form is open, so user can still use it in any other case. Thanks.